# Error executing big sql statements

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am trying to run a very very long sql statement but I get this error

> Thread stack overrun: 230352 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 32000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

How can I assign a bigger stack or solve this problem?? I am using wamp, localhost.

Comment: Use `--thread_stack=#` as it says?

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack

Comment: How can I assign it I am using wamp?

Comment: because it is written in other answers to edit in my.cnf but there is no suck file ni wamp. How can I set it?

Comment: `C:\MySQL\bin\my.ini` Where 'MySQL' is the path where you installed MySQL.

Comment: In wamp the file is called my.ini. You can edit it by using the wampmanager menus as follows. wampmanager->MySQL->my.ini

Answer (score 2):

If you have queries that large then you really should be passing parameters into a stored procedure, or batch execution of the SQL. You can change the WAMP MySQL initialization if required, or just use PHPMyAdmin

Comment: WAMP my.ini is usually in Drive:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[version]\my.ini and here is more info on the thread stack for you... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack